# Проблема с кодированием

Tags: javascript, кодировка, кириллица, геокодирование

В общем есть скрипт puppeteer который парсит ответ от сервера:

```
    const response = await this.page.waitForResponse((response) =>
    {
        return response.url().includes('/chat') && response.status() === 200;
    });

    const responseBody = await response.text();

    const lines = responseBody.match(/data: {"delta":"([^"]*)"}\n/g).map((match) => match.match(/data: {"delta":"([^"]*)"}\n/)[1]);
    const text = lines.join('');

    console.log('тут проблема ' + text);
```

В переменной text появляется вот это, и не могу ее декодировать в читабельный вид, помогите как?

````
 ÐšÐ¾Ð½ÐµÑ‡Ð½Ð¾! Ð’Ð¾Ñ‚ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¸Ð¼ÐµÑ€ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾ÑÑ‚Ð¾Ð¹ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ð³Ñ€Ð°Ð¼Ð¼Ñ‹ Ð½Ð° C++, ÐºÐ¾Ñ‚Ð¾Ñ€Ð°Ñ Ð²Ñ‹Ð²Ð¾Ð´Ð¸Ñ‚ÐŸÑ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚, Ð¼Ð¸Ñ€ Ð½Ð° ÑÐºÑ€Ð°Ð½:\n\n```cpp\n#include <iostream>\n\nint main() {\n    std::coutÐŸÑ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚, Ð¼Ð¸Ñ€ << std::endl;\n    return 0;\n}\n```\n\nÐ­Ñ‚Ð° Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ð³Ñ€Ð°Ð¼Ð¼Ð° Ð¸ÑÐ¿Ð¾Ð»ÑŒÐ·ÑƒÐµÑ‚ Ð±Ð¸Ð±Ð»Ð¸Ð¾Ñ‚ÐµÐºÑƒ `iostream` Ð´Ð»Ñ Ð²Ð²Ð¾Ð´Ð°-Ð²Ñ‹Ð²Ð¾Ð´Ð° Ð¸ Ð²Ñ‹Ð²Ð¾Ð´Ð¸Ñ‚ ÑÑ‚Ñ€Ð¾ÐºÑƒÐŸÑ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚, Ð¼Ð¸Ñ€ Ñ Ð¿Ð¾Ð¼Ð¾Ñ‰ÑŒÑŽ `std::cout`. Ð—Ð°Ñ‚ÐµÐ¼ Ð¾Ð½Ð° Ð²Ð¾Ð·Ð²Ñ€Ð°Ñ‰Ð°ÐµÑ‚ 0, ÑƒÐºÐ°Ð·Ñ‹Ð²Ð°Ñ Ð½Ð° ÑƒÑÐ¿ÐµÑˆÐ½Ð¾Ðµ Ð·Ð°Ð²ÐµÑ€ÑˆÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ð³Ñ€Ð°Ð¼Ð¼Ñ‹.
````

Пробовал utf8 1252 1251 и тд.

```
 iconv.encode(iconv.decode(text, 'utf8'), 'Windows-1252')
```

Comment: попробуйте получить строку без всяких преобразований (т.е., без использования этого вашего js/puppeter/и т.п.). просто каким-нибудь curl-ом/wget-ом и тому подобным. и смотрите, что именно там вам сервер выдаёт.

Comment: на странице все норм и со строкой все норм, просто ее нужно както преобразовать, некоторые сайты в гугле декодирую строку, но пытаюсь сделать тоже самое не работает

Comment: хм. `ÐšÐ¾Ð½ÐµÑ‡Ð½Ð¾!` — если это «норм», то в чём же тогда вопрос?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/JgtjpMC.png

Answer (score 0):

нашел рабочий код php

````
<?php
$str = ' ÐšÐ¾Ð½ÐµÑ‡Ð½Ð¾! Ð’Ð¾Ñ‚ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¸Ð¼ÐµÑ€ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾ÑÑ‚Ð¾Ð¹ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ð³Ñ€Ð°Ð¼Ð¼Ñ‹ Ð½Ð° C++, ÐºÐ¾Ñ‚Ð¾Ñ€Ð°Ñ Ð²Ñ‹Ð²Ð¾Ð´Ð¸Ñ‚ÐŸÑ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚, Ð¼Ð¸Ñ€ Ð½Ð° ÑÐºÑ€Ð°Ð½:\n\n```cpp\n#include <iostream>\n\nint main() {\n    std::coutÐŸÑ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚, Ð¼Ð¸Ñ€ << std::endl;\n    return 0;\n}\n```\n\nÐ­Ñ‚Ð° Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ð³Ñ€Ð°Ð¼Ð¼Ð° Ð¸ÑÐ¿Ð¾Ð»ÑŒÐ·ÑƒÐµÑ‚ Ð±Ð¸Ð±Ð»Ð¸Ð¾Ñ‚ÐµÐºÑƒ `iostream` Ð´Ð»Ñ Ð²Ð²Ð¾Ð´Ð°-Ð²Ñ‹Ð²Ð¾Ð´Ð° Ð¸ Ð²Ñ‹Ð²Ð¾Ð´Ð¸Ñ‚ ÑÑ‚Ñ€Ð¾ÐºÑƒÐŸÑ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚, Ð¼Ð¸Ñ€ Ñ Ð¿Ð¾Ð¼Ð¾Ñ‰ÑŒÑŽ `std::cout`. Ð—Ð°Ñ‚ÐµÐ¼ Ð¾Ð½Ð° Ð²Ð¾Ð·Ð²Ñ€Ð°Ñ‰Ð°ÐµÑ‚ 0, ÑƒÐºÐ°Ð·Ñ‹Ð²Ð°Ñ Ð½Ð° ÑƒÑÐ¿ÐµÑˆÐ½Ð¾Ðµ Ð·Ð°Ð²ÐµÑ€ÑˆÐµÐ½Ð¸Ðµ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ð³Ñ€Ð°Ð¼Ð¼Ñ‹.';

$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, "Windows-1252", "UTF-8");

var_dump($str);
?>
````

js пока не нашел

Comment: Конечно! Вот пример про�?той программы на C++, котора�? выводит на �?кран фразуПривет, мир!```cpp\n#include <iostream>\n\nint main() {\n    std::coutПривет, мир << std::endl;\n    return 0;\n}\n```\n\nЭта программа и�?пользует библиотеку `iostream` дл�? работы �? вводом-выводом. Функци�? `main` �?вл�?ет�?�? точкой входа в программу, и в данном �?лучае она про�?то выводит фразуПривет, мир на �?кран. Затем она возвращает значение 0, что означает у�?пешное завершение программы.
======================
        const decodedData2 = iconv.encode(text, 'win1252');
проблемы с буквами(